# bitcoin, is there any starting amount?

Tags: cryptocurrency

There is some kind of input how bitcoin is start (offer). Is bitcoin is depends on how much we ***'invest'*** so we get different ***'amount'*** in return?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Bitcoin (or other crypto-currencies) that have no bearing on personal finance are off-topic. There is a separate http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea the bitcoin stackexchange is a technical site, personal finance sites' perpetual allergy to cryptocurrency is kind of old now

Comment: @CQM Noted. Yet, the minimum increment for Bitcoin is a technical question, IMHO. (If that is what the question is asking about; can't tell.)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea, I disagree.  That's like saying the minimum increment of a dollar is a technical question and unanswerable here.  (though this question is clearly vague)

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you're asking about the flurry of Initial Coin Offerings (ICOs) that have been taking place.  Stay FAR far far far far away from these.  Ethereum (ETH)(not bitcoin) has a contract function and these ridiculous "startup" coins are taking advantage of that function to issue "tokens" for their project.  Some of these projects are as ridiculous as storing medical records in a blockchain.  These ICOs are very lucrative for the developers and a waste of time money and energy for everyone else.  They are billed as investments though you get no ownership or control over the operation and some even "guarantee" interest payments.  These all are likely to fail in the next few to several months as the interest wanes and fools stop showing up to hand over money.

There are a number of outlets that will sell you bitcoin if you feel inclined to own some.  Stay away from all the garbage "investment" schemes that use bitcoin or other crypto.

Comment: storing medical records in a blockchain is one of the most obvious uses for a blockchain though, although there is plenty to criticize about the proposed execution

Comment: @CQM, I disagree.

Comment: it would just be the hashes of that kind of document not necessarily the actual record, just one attempt at a central database and standardized format

Comment: I understand why people think it's a fine idea, I don't agree that it's practical at all and think "investing" in a non-equity, non-controlling, nonsensical unproven or non-existent use case is little more than outright robbery.

Comment: its no different than a venue selling tickets to gain access to the concert and using the proceeds for higher production value. typically the tokens in ICOs are supposed to have some a within the system being created. I'm not giving rebuttals to your criticisms, they're still there: lofty valuations, lack of investor protections, but some of your talking points are off

Comment: You don't buy a concert ticket to help the venue through a renovation, you buy a concert ticket to see a concert.  There just so happens to be an overwhelming amount of speculation around the concert tickets at the moment, and no concert is scheduled.  These ICOs are not investments and the organizations orchestrating them are not "startups."  Have you seen the ICO calendar, it's utter lunacy.

Comment: yes, I have. the concept isn't inherently flawed, and the concert analogy doesn't fail, one entity sells tickets at a premium and makes a profit and chooses to expand their operation or not. The OTC Bulletin Board reverse merger calendar, the UK's AIM market, the IPOs on respected market calendars - and to continue the analogy - upcoming concerts are all much more numerous and much more dubious. It is up to you to filter the crap. Sure, its like 1929 when no respected financial organization was filtering new offerings and grouping them all together.

Comment: Filtering the ICOs for crap would leave none.

Comment: I don't disagree

Comment: On that point you and I can agree to not disagree lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you own any amount of bitcoin as an investment, then you will keep that same amount of bitcoin and hope to sell it at a higher price. if you use bitcoin in this way then it is analogous to stocks. bitcoin is not intended to be used in this way, but historically that has been very profitable.